# DH parameters of a serial manipulator RRRRRR

Tags: manipulator, dh-parameters

I am trying to find the forward kinematics of this manipulator in the picture using DH notation. All of the joints are rotational.

[image: Manipulator picture]

I managed to get to the third joint. The parameter table is below.

| Joint | Theta | d | a | alpha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q_1 | d_1 | 0 | pi/2 |
| 2 | q_2 | 0 | d_2 | 0 |
| 3 | q_3 | 0 | d_3 |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |

I am not sure what the alpha for joint 3 should be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* This looks like a homework question, and on stack exchange, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please edit your question to add this information and take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest watching [Robotics 1 U1 (Kinematics) S5 (HTM) P2 (HTM by Denavit Hartenberg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WRhVqQaZTE&list=PLT_0lwItn0sDBE98BsbaZezflB96ws12b&index=18&t=325s), to learn how to find DH-parameter table.

Alpha values can be found out by the rotation of the first frame to the second frame's x-axis to match the z-axis with second frame. Therefore, here the alpha value for joint-3 would be pi/2 when we rotate frame 3 around frame 4's x-axis to match the z-axis.